# C code to MIPS (offset)

Tags: mips, offset

Suppose $t0 stores the base address of word array, $s0 is associated with position, and $s1 is associated with offset.I have to convert the following program segment into Assembly and write down the resulting array content

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
position = 0
offset = 1
while position < 11:
array[position] = array [position + offset]
position = position + 1;
```

so far i have written this-

```
   .data

array:  
 .word 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
  counter:  .word 11

lw $t1,counter
 la $t0,array
li $s0,0
li $s1,1

loop:

beq $s0,$t1,end
lb $s0,0($t0)
add $s0,$s0,@s1
sw $s0,($s0)
addi $s0,$s0,1
addi $t0,$t0,4 
j loop

end:
```

i dont know how to move forward from here , can anyone help

Comment: Why do you have to convert this from C to assy?  Today we have compilers that do that for us.

Comment: This looks like a homework or quiz question so we will expect you to do most of the work. **Add comments** to the assembly code explaining how it relates to the C code. **Explain why** you think your code is wrong or incomplete...and be **specific**.